# Mixing java and scala in a single project - tests in scala, core in java

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, testing

Suppose that one prefers the functional style testing framework (e.g. specs) and doesn't like the ones which are industry standard for Java (e.g. JUnit). Is it a good practice to have a Java project with the unit/integration tests written only in scala (and the rest of the projects written in java)? Are there any drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: If your team is up for it, then go for it.

Comment: Most Scala/Java interop problems come when going Java->Scala.  Scala->Java is pretty flawless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some experience about this, we used that before.

Drawbacks:

1. **Scala knowledge**: For the developer point of view, they will not learn too much if they only write scala code for test, because some other Scala feature like implicit, type level programming and so on will not be **well** used.
2. **Type Conversion**: Type conversion is very annoying. Almost all the Java Collection is mutable like ArrayList, HashMap and so on, but Scala Seq, List, Map, it will be imported as an immutable collection, so you need to convert these all the time by using Scala.collection.JavaConversion._. Not to mention that other type like BigDecimal in java, you need to convert it as well.
3. **Slow compilation**: If you use Specs2, it may **relatively** increase your **compilation time**, personally, I think it may use implicit too much, every test method has to return **MatchResult** , this type is implicit look up not explicitly. If you write a test without any matcher, you can see the implicit not found error. Anyway, compilation may be time consuming.
4. **Lack of IDE support to do TDD**, I am using intellij 13 ultimate edition, in Java, I enjoy to do TDD and it is quick, but in Scala test, it doesnt support it very well, **alt + enter** doesnt give me too many useful options
5. **Dont try to mix import Java and Scala code**, so right now in your project, Scala code is using Java code in test package, if some Java test code imports Scala code, it is possible to make IDE confused. Intellij is not smart enough to compile which one first. We have this problem as well, we just manually compile Scala test code and then build project, but it is a little frustrating.

I am not a big fan of **only using Scala for testing**. Scala is an amazing language providing so many features to let you write **expressive and elegant** code.

**Several suggestions** for trying to use Scala on Java core project (may off the topic)

**Microservice**: As far as I know, my friends from Java core project are using    microservice as solution to write Scala code on top of Java. However,    in some scenario, it may increase unnecessary maintenance effort.

**Jar**: you can also separate it by creating Scala project and then package a jar, publish to your company Nexus, and then import it in your Java project. I think this is a clean solution, because they both sit on top of JVM and Dev will not complaint about compilation issue.

I think other people may have similar experience as well, I hope I can learn it :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically is possible doing so, but I don't think it's the right way to go.
If your team know / willing to learn scala then they probably will want to write the entire code in scala and not just the tests (or at least do so for new code).
If the team dont know scala, the learning curve is high, and since tests usually limited scope they will not learn from it a lot.
If you try to sneak scala using tests then you may get the opposite effect.
There are problems with scala (like strong IDE support, long compilations, integration with 3rd party tools, etc..). IMHO it's well worth pay it when you develop in scala, but not if limited for tests.

If all you want is more functional way to write your tests I recommend you using [Spock](http://spockframework.org). It is a very nice testing and specification framework for Java and Groovy. Since groovy intend itself be familiar to java developers they may feel more comfortable using it.
I started using it before, but then rewrite the entire app in scala :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it in couple of projects for e.g. using Spock(groovy), scala-test. It is quite effective way to evaluate, learn and play with new programming languages. 

**Are there any drawbacks?**
If your team uses continuous integration then probably you need to spend some time to configure Maven/Gradle to include your tests and other configurations so that CI can build it.